# Integrating Powermock with Mockito - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

Am truing to integrate Mockito, JUnit and Powermock using following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.19</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

While running IT test following error appears:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;
```

I have spent long time to figure out proper artifacts versions but after changin it and fixing one error next one appears :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies versions are way too old.
I would suggest to go for the newest 2.x releases:

```xml
<properties>
  ...

  <version.mockito>2.23.4</version.mockito>
  <version.powermock>2.0.2</version.powermock>
</properties>

<dependencies>
   ...

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>${version.mockito}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>${version.powermock}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>${version.powermock}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>${version.powermock}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This comes from a working project, if you keep getting errors please expand the question including the Java code.

Comment: Thanks Qword, it is working, appreciate this how you specify right configuration :)